# FPDF Header Causes Second Column on Second Page to Break to Third Page

Tags: fpdf

I have a Header consisting of 2 cells one above the other extending about quarter of width aligned to left and another over these 2 cells extending width of page with text aligned right and border bottom.

Then I have rows of text in two columns, where all rows may extend three pages or more and obviously need a header printed on each page. Each row consists of two MultiCells. When I don't print the Header, the two columns of text are printing fine. However, when I print the Header, the right column of the first row on the second page doesn't print until the third page, and then the rows and columns print fine on third page, with only one left cell printed on the second page, and the left cell printed on 2nd page missing from 3rd page.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Help would be much appreciated.

Here is the code ...

```
require('vendor/fpdf181/fpdf.php');
require('../includes/php/fpdf.class.php');

$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','Letter');

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);

$w=50;
$x=$pdf->GetX();
$y=$pdf->GetY();
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,'Created:');
$pdf->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
$w=146;
$nowLocal = convertUTCToLocal($now, $_SESSION['tz_offset_from_utc_in_secs']);
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,$nowLocal);

$w=50;
$x=$pdf->GetX();
$y=$pdf->GetY();
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,'Last Updated:');
$pdf->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
$w=146;
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,$lastUpdated);

$pdf->Ln(5); // linebreak

$w=50;
$x=$pdf->GetX();
$y=$pdf->GetY();
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,'Category:');
$pdf->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
$w=146;
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,$appType);

$w=50;
$x=$pdf->GetX();
$y=$pdf->GetY();
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,'Type:');
$pdf->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
$w=146;
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,$appSubType.' ('.$appSubTypeNotes.')');

$w=50;
$x=$pdf->GetX();
$y=$pdf->GetY();
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,'Meeting Type:');
$pdf->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
$w=146;
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,$meetingType);

$pdf->Ln(5); // linebreak

$w=50;
$x=$pdf->GetX();
$y=$pdf->GetY();
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,'Contact Name:');
$pdf->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
$w=146;
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,$contactName);

$w=50;
$x=$pdf->GetX();
$y=$pdf->GetY();
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,'Contact Phone:');
$pdf->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
$w=146;
$pdf->Multicell($w,5,$contactPhone);
```

This is the fpdf.class.php file ...

```
<?php

class PDF extends FPDF 
{

    function Header()
    {

    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',20);
    $x=$this->GetX();
    $y=$this->GetY();

    $this->Cell(98,10,'Company Name',0,0);

    $this->SetXY($x,$y+15);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',16);
    $this->Cell(98,10,'REPORT TITLE',0,0);

    $this->SetXY($x,$y);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    $str = <<<END
Address 1
Address 2
Address 3
Phone Number
Fax Number
END;
    $this->MultiCell(196,5,$str,'B','R');

    //$this->SetXY($x,$y+25);

    // Line break
    $this->Ln(10);
    }

    function Footer()
    {
        // Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);

        $this->SetFont('Arial','',12);

        // Print centered page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo(),0,0,'C');
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: I only included a few rows in the code for brevity's sake.

Comment: I take it back. I got rid of the header and the right column on the second page breaks to third page still, leaving only one left column row on second page and printing the rest on third page.

Comment: I basically adapted instructions from http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php to get the multicolumn table to page break properly.